# Highlight Current Tag in wp_tag_cloud

Tags: php, functions, tags

I'm in the middle of building a website and one of the pages will be a glossary. The first page of the glossary will display a list of all the words, which are custom post types assigned into a custom taxonomy called "letter" which pulls the first letter of the word.

On top of the glossary, there is a "navigation" which is a a wp_tag_cloud of all the `letter`s (A-Z). The user can then click into the letter, and the page displays all of the words that start with that letter.

The question I have is that if there is a way I can add a `current-tag` styling to the tag that I'm currently viewing.

My code for this so far is this:

```
  <!-- Glossary Search -->
  <div class="search-container">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="show-search col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-3">
       <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
          <div class="letter-list row-fluid">  


           <!-- IMPORTANT --> <?php wp_tag_cloud( array( 'taxonomy' => 'letter', 'format' => 'flat', 'hide_empty' => false) ); ?>


            <input type="text" value="Search the Glossary" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search the Glossary';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search the Glossary') {this.value = '';}" name="s" id="glossarySearch" />
          </div>
      </form>
      </div> <!-- end shows-search -->
    </div> <!-- end container -->
  </div> <!-- end search-container -->
```

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 4):

When you are in a tag template, a body class is added with term-{termID}, so you can hook in "wp_generate_tag_cloud_data" to check if class is present and add custom class to the tag ;)

```
 function tribalpixel_tag_cloud_class_active($tags_data) {

        $body_class = get_body_class();

        foreach ($tags_data as $key => $tag) {
            if(in_array('term-'.$tag['id'], $body_class)) {
                $tags_data[$key]['class'] =  $tags_data[$key]['class'] ." active-tag";
            } 
        }
        return $tags_data;
    }

    add_filter('wp_generate_tag_cloud_data', 'tribalpixel_tag_cloud_class_active');
```

after that you simply use CSS to style ;)

Answer (score 3):

From quick look at source tag cloud doesn't account for current tag and is not easily tweaked to implement that in code. However it does output class which includes tags ID - `class='tag-link-$tag_id'`.

What you could do is hook into `wp_head`, check if you are in tag archive and output small inline CSS block which styles the element for current ID as required.